# Backtesting multiple stocks using Python

Tags: python, trading

I am now using Pyalgotrade, which is a popular python library for testing trading strategy. I want to write a loop which can test couples of stocks one after another.

Suppose I want to put the following 6 stocks into this strategy, and tun each stock one time and get several results. How can I write that loop?

Stocks = [AAPL, EBAY, NFLX, BBY, GOOG, WBAI]

```
from pyalgotrade import strategy
from pyalgotrade.barfeed import yahoofeed
from pyalgotrade.technical import ma
from pyalgotrade.tools import yahoofinance


class MyStrategy(strategy.BacktestingStrategy):
    def __init__(self, feed, instrument, smaPeriod):
        strategy.BacktestingStrategy.__init__(self, feed, 1000)
        self.__position = None
        self.__instrument = instrument
        # We'll use adjusted close values instead of regular close values.
        self.setUseAdjustedValues(True)
        self.__sma = ma.SMA(feed[instrument].getAdjCloseDataSeries(), smaPeriod)

    def onEnterOk(self, position):
        execInfo = position.getEntryOrder().getExecutionInfo()
        self.info("BUY at $%.2f" % (execInfo.getPrice()))

    def onEnterCanceled(self, position):
        self.__position = None

    def onExitOk(self, position):
        execInfo = position.getExitOrder().getExecutionInfo()
        self.info("SELL at $%.2f" % (execInfo.getPrice()))
        self.__position = None

    def onExitCanceled(self, position):
        # If the exit was canceled, re-submit it.
        self.__position.exitMarket()

    def onBars(self, bars):
        # Wait for enough bars to be available to calculate a SMA.
        if self.__sma[-1] is None:
            return

        bar = bars[self.__instrument]
        # If a position was not opened, check if we should enter a long position.
        if self.__position is None:
            if bar.getAdjClose() > self.__sma[-1]:
                # Enter a buy market order for 10 shares. The order is good till canceled.
                self.__position = self.enterLong(self.__instrument, 10, True)
        # Check if we have to exit the position.
        elif bar.getAdjClose() < self.__sma[-1]:
            self.__position.exitMarket()



def run_strategy(smaPeriod):
    instruments = ["AAPL"]

        # Download the bars.
    feed = yahoofinance.build_feed(instruments, 2011, 2013, ".")

        # Evaluate the strategy with the feed's bars.
    myStrategy = MyStrategy(feed, "AAPL", smaPeriod)
    myStrategy.run()
    print "Final portfolio value: $%.2f" % myStrategy.getBroker().getEquity()

run_strategy(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def run_strategy(smaPeriod,inst):

        # Download the bars.
    feed = yahoofinance.build_feed([inst], 2011, 2013, ".")

        # Evaluate the strategy with the feed's bars.
    myStrategy = MyStrategy(feed, inst, smaPeriod)
    myStrategy.run()
    print "Final portfolio value: $%.2f" % myStrategy.getBroker().getEquity()
def main():
    instruments = ["AAPL","EBAY", "NFLX", "BBY"]
    for inst in instruments:
            run_strategy(10,inst)
if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess [ScrenningTale](https://www.screeningtale.com/screener) will be a better and easier backtesting option for those having limited knowledge of coding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32363398)